# Add subtract mask on top of a UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to put a UIView on top of another UIView as a subtract mask. Is it possible to do that?

I have a rectangular photo and I want to put a mask on top of it that has black rounded corners. I don't want to put the rounded corners on the photo itself. Essentially the mask is kind of like a photo frame that you can look through.

[image: Photo of a tree with a mask rounding the corners]

Answer (score 0):

I did that once using [this](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/making-a-hole-in-uiview-with-calayer/) as reference. It's basically setting up a `CAShapeLayer` on a `UIView` on the top of your `UIImageView`. This is what you need:

```
// Add image view to the root view
let image = UIImage(named: "SomeImage.jpg")
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
imageView.image = image
view.addSubview(imageView)

// Add mask view on the of image view
let maskView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
maskView.backgroundColor = .black
view.addSubview(maskView)

// The layer that defines your maskView's behavior
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = maskView.bounds

// Create the frame for the circle.
let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
let roundedRectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskView.frame, cornerRadius: radius)

let path = UIBezierPath(rect: maskView.bounds)

// Append the rounded rect to the external path
path.append(roundedRectPath)

maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
maskView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works but my issue now is when I take my original view and get it as an image, the corners are rounded. I want it to be not rounded when I get an image from the view which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar idea as other mask, But just use a UIView mask.

```
             let maskView = UIView.init()
            maskView.frame = view.bounds


            let shape = CAShapeLayer.init()
            shape.path =  UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: maskView.bounds).cgPath
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


            maskView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
            maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
            view.mask = maskView // view is the imageView.
```